# Http Live Streaming for iPhone and why we use .m3u8 file

Tags: iphone, ios, html, webserver, http-live-streaming

I have done all that from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592485/http-live-streaming)
I have also made .ts and m3u8 file. In local server and live server i can play mp4 file like

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </object>
 </video>
```

**But i have problem with playing .m3u8 file**

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
 <source src="movie.m3u8" type="video/m3u8" />
 </object>
 </video>
```

My mediafilesegmenter created two .ts file and one .m3u8 . My m3u8 file is

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
 #EXT-X-VERSION:4
 #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
 #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
 #EXT-X-I-FRAMES-ONLY
 #EXTINF:1.0117,    
 #EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8084@376
 fileSequence0.ts
 #EXTINF:1.0117,    
 #EXT-X-BYTERANGE:7332@36096   and so on....
```

So is there any problem in mime.types because i wrote all the confusions in mime.types see like -

```
 application/x-mpegURL                          m3u8
 video/MP2T                                     ts

 AddType appliction/x-mpegURL                   m3u8
 AddType video/MP2T                             ts

 #application/x-mpegURL                          m3u8
 #video/MP2T                                     ts

 application/x-mpegURL.m3u8
 video/MP2T.ts

 #application/x-mpegURL.m3u8
 #video/MP2T.ts

 #AddType application/x-mpegURL                   m3u8
 #AddType video/MP2T                             ts

 #AddType application/x-mpegURL.m3u8
 #AddType video/MP2T.ts

 AddType application/x-mpegURL.m3u8
 AddType video/MP2T.ts
```

**I can't play .m3u8 file in VLC** and got that error [Link](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:28ff)

Comment: Well, you typed `appliction` instead of `application`. That could be giving you grief.

Comment: oh yeah i think so ... i will check that otherwise i will edit that

Comment: na its not working man. still have same problem

Comment: What is the error message when you try accessing the m3u8 and ts file individually using say `curl`?

Comment: i haven't get any error and how can check that and i m using dashcode for html. i am using in html right now. i can't play in html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your conf is

```
AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
AddType video/MP2T .ts
```

it should work for apache. I'm not sure if it's your .ts or .m3u8 problem, so I suggest the following:

- Download example .ts and .m3u8 file from Apple and test them on your server
- check if there is empty lines in the index file, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438680/http-live-streaming-not-working-on-apache)

Comment: yeah i can run .ts and .m3u8 file from apple and i can also      run my .ts file but not .m3u8 file. One thing more rename .m3u8 file...will it be a problem or not

Comment: Then it should go back to the procedure when you generate .ts and .m3u8. Did you rename the .m3u8 file after generation?

Comment: yeah i renamed .m3u8 file but now i created new one .ts and .m3u8 without renaming (Created files are fileSequence0.ts ... and iframe_index.m3u8). i can play .ts file but not .m3u8 file.. can you make it for me .ts file and .m3u8 file but i dont think so there is problem in files. and one thing more i config mime type (application/x-mpegURL .m3u8 video/MP2T .ts) in /etc/apache2/mime.types  not in httpd.config

Comment: 1. will it work if you play the index file with VLC?
2. which segmenter have you used?

Comment: it is not working with VLC. i use media file segmenter tool for converting.

Comment: did you use command like this `mediafilesegmenter  -f  [destinationPath] [videoSource]  -t  1`

Comment: i use mediafilesegmenter -t 10 movie.mp4 ... and why u use -t 1

Comment: and it will convert my file into .ts and .m3u8 file then i move it to my sites and documents folder for hosting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15457/discussion-between-pravi-jay-and-babypanda)

Comment: i have done that sir just now please tell me about live streaming this  is VOD .. now i want to do live streaming like dvr cameras

Answer (score 1):

The video tag source type `video/m3u8` is *not* valid on the iOS platform. I suggest you simply omit declaring the source attribute, which is not required.

If you really want to specify the source type, i.e. to allow non-compatible clients to select another source, I have found that `audio/x-mpegurl` works.

Comment: instead of video/m3u8 what i have to write on that...please write one example  ... ok i will write audio/x-mpegurl.

Comment: what is the extension of audio/x-mpegurl (.ts or what)

Comment: extension is `.m3u8`. source line should read `<source src="movie.m3u8" type="audio/x-mpegurl" />`

Comment: so think it will just play audio or both

Comment: Actually, any of the following should work: `application/x-mpegurl`, `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`, `audio/x-mpegurl`.

Comment: i write that code   <source src="stream.m3u8" type="audio/x-mpegurl" /> but in vain

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15422/discussion-between-pravi-jay-and-gil)

Answer (score 0):

The m3u8 you're using was generated for seeking only. See `EXT-X-I-FRAMES-ONLY` as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-I_FRAME_PLAYLIST